# Android 6 + WebView + Rangy library = SIGSEGV Crash

Tags: javascript, android

Im using Webview + Rangy Class Applier Module (by Tim)

after a button click, it load a javascript `webview.loadUrl("javascript:applyColor(color1)");`

and the function

```
function applyColor(colorCSSClass) {
applier = rangy.createClassApplier(colorCSSClass);
applier.toggleSelection();
//Remove Other css colours
}
```

and for some weird reason, after some applied colors the app crash and  i receive this error :

```
 W/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_ldd_control:475>: ioctl fd 36 code 0x40180917 (IOCTL_KGSL_CMDSTREAM_FREEMEMONTIMESTAMP_CTXTID) failed: errno 16 Device or resource busy
    W/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_ldd_control:475>: ioctl fd 36 code 0x40180917 (IOCTL_KGSL_CMDSTREAM_FREEMEMONTIMESTAMP_CTXTID) failed: errno 16 Device or resource busy
    W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
    W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
    W/google-breakpad: 3.0.0.5
    W/google-breakpad: 3005
    W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
    A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x7b in tid 25790 (RenderThread)
    D/HyLog: D: Wrong tag (927 : loadPreData() : frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics/TypefaceHyFontManager.cpp)
```

UPDATE: this error does not occurs in Android 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND THE SOLUTION, ITS A OLD PROBLEM, occurs for some people and for others not, for me was in android 6.0

The Solution:

```
webview.load... //load your html
```

than after the loading:

```
                webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                Paint p = new Paint();
                webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, p);
```

It seems to hit a little performance when you talk about Smooth scrolling, dont know if its version related or is there any fix, if i find or someone, please, post here

no crashs anymore after this